# Finding Logs on GCP App Engine using Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

I have a very basic go application on GCP that I am attempted to get connected to a CloudSQL Postgres. I have the following code that is failing:

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres",CONNECTION_STRING)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error: The data source arguments are not valid: " + err.Error())
    return
}
log.Print("Attempting to connect to database")
err = db.Ping()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error: Could not establish a connection with the database: " + err.Error())
    return
}
```

The code is failing at the second log.Fatal call, however I cannot find how to read the entire log in GCP so I can see what the error was. Does anyone know where to find the full log?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use the App Engine Go SDK on [App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/logs/) or write to the stdout or stderr on [Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/writing-application-logs#writing_application_logs_1), you should be able to see the logs for your application in your Developer Console > Logging [section](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview).

Answer (score 0):

We have various ways of obtain logs either with default logs that automatically show up in your Google Cloud Console, or via the Google Cloud Client Library to write additional logs. You can see the [details here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging).

If you think the information you need is already logged, then simply make sure you are using the log viewer properly. You can see instructions for GO [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/logs/#request_logs_vs_application_logs).